# PerformanceCounter (and Performance Monitor) showing different result than Task Manager

Tags: c#, .net, performance, resources

I have the following code:

```
PerformanceCounter c = new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "_Total");
```

And then I use it with: `c.NextValue()`

What I get is around twice as high as Task Manager manager shows as the cpu utilization. Though my cpu has 2 cores, as far as I know [that's not supposed to make a difference](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnetinterop/2007/02/02/system-diagnostics-performancecounter-and-processor-time-on-multi-core-or-multi-cpu/). So why is this happening? Or am I wrong about the dual core causing it? (Though searching for some time, I can't find any documentation for a list of performance counters.)

**EDIT**

As suggested in a comment, I tried perfmon (Performance Monitor) and it shows the same result I get. Why the discrepancy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/winserverperformance/2009/08/06/interpreting-cpu-utilization-for-performance-analysis/) you should use "Processor Information" instead of "Processor" if you want to match the exact value of the task manager. Question is what value is right, but that is a design decision I guess.

> For someone performing performance testing and analysis, the ability
>   to log CPU utilization data over time is critical. A data collector
>   set can be configured via logman.exe to log the “% Processor
>   Time”counter in the “Processor Information” object for this purpose.

```
PerformanceCounter c = new PerformanceCounter("Processor Information", "% Processor Time", "_Total");
```

Should do it.

Comment: Thanks. But that made no difference.

Comment: Hm. Interesting. Are you taking at least two samples with 1 sec in between which is required for the proper calculation?

Comment: Also, does it match perfmon values?

Comment: I'm taking a sample every second continuously.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Perfmon matches mine, not Task Manager's. Strange.

Comment: Yes this is a known thing and can be explained. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0435e7c5-3cda-41a0-953e-7fa462fde03b/perfmon-process-processor-time-vs-task-managers-cpu-usage-for-monitoring-a-specific-user?forum=perfmon.

Answer (score 2):

If you use this, you can get the same result with the task manager :

```
 cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter(
            "Processor Information",
            "% Processor Utility",
            "_Total",
            true
        );
```

Comment: amazing ! I looked for this everywhere thanks

Comment: dude, it just hits to 137% on windows 10 pro